# Bucle anidado con for

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Buenas tardes foro tengo el siguiente bucle for.

```
while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            $LineaI = $resultados['linea'];
            $modelI = $resultados['modelo'];
            $familiaI = $resultados['familia'];
            $columnas = $resultados['racks'];
            $ColumContent = $resultados['racksonbuffer'];;

            //Output
            $mensaje .= '
              <tbody>
              <td>'.$LineaI.'</td>
              <td>'.$modelI.'</td>
              <td>'.$familiaI.'</td>
            ';

                for($x=1; $x<=$columnas; $x++){
                        $mensaje .= "<td></td>";
                }


             $mensaje .= '</tbody>';
            

        };
        $mensaje .= '</table>';
```

Estoy generando las columnas con el numero que obtengo de la base de datos...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo es correcto...
Lo siguiente es lograr que dentro del mensaje  **$mensaje .=**  yo necesito poner un valor de texto pero solo hasta un limite, para eso tengo el campo en mi base de datos **$ColumContent = $resultados['racksonbuffer'];**

Por ejemplo en el primer registro genere 15 columnas pero solo necesito meter un valor de texto dentro del  para 5 que necesito hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este deberia ser resultado(lo modifique con inspector).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando dices _Hasta aquí todo es correcto..._, no es del todo cierto, porque estás generando un HTML mal formado, creando `<tbody>` en cada iteración del ciclo, pero debería ser `<tr>`. Para lo otro, solo cambia el for: `for($x=1; $x<=5; $x++)` para especificar el total de columnas que vas a mostrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucione mi problema de la siguiente manera.

Agregue la diferencia.

```
$diferencia = $racks - $racksUsados;
```

Y agregue el siguiente for debajo del otro for.

```
for ($k=1; $k <= $diferencia ; $k++) {
   $mensaje .= "<td> </td>";
}
```

Y así quedo el código.

```
while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            $LineaI = $resultados['linea'];
            $modelI = $resultados['modelo'];
            $familiaI = $resultados['familia'];
            $racks = $resultados['racks'];
            $racksUsados = $resultados['racksonbuffer'];
            $diferencia = $racks - $racksUsados;

            //Output
            $mensaje .= '
              <tbody>
              <td>'.$LineaI.'</td>
              <td>'.$modelI.'</td>
              <td>'.$familiaI.'</td>
            ';

                for($x=1; $x<=$racksUsados; $x++){
                  $mensaje .= "<td><span class='oi oi-spreadsheet'></span></td>";
                }
                for ($k=1; $k <= $diferencia ; $k++) {
                  $mensaje .= "<td> </td>";
                }


             $mensaje .= '</tbody>';
            

        };
        $mensaje .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

podría ser algo así:
si dentro del FOR la columna cumple la condición que es menor al contador (racksonbuffer) se pintará.

(debes sacar el TBODY del while ,revisa la sintaxis porque no tengo como probarla ahora.)

```
$mensaje .= '<tbody>';

while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            $LineaI = $resultados['linea'];
            $modelI = $resultados['modelo'];
            $familiaI = $resultados['familia'];
            $columnas = $resultados['racks'];
            $ColumContent = $resultados['racksonbuffer'];;

            //Output
            $mensaje .= '
              <td>'.$LineaI.'</td>
              <td>'.$modelI.'</td>
              <td>'.$familiaI.'</td>
            ';

                for($x=1; $x<=$columnas; $x++){
                       if($x<= $ColumContent){
                         $mensaje .= "<td>*</td>";
                       }
                       else{
                        $mensaje .= "<td></td>";
                        }
                }

        };
        $mensaje .= '</tbody>'; 
        $mensaje .= '</table>';
```